# Grep from a file and output pattern if not found

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file, `ids_list.csv`, containing a list of ids, one on each line.

I also have a log file, in which I want to find the ids from `ids_list.txt`.

What I want is to print to a `result.txt` file the line from the log file if the pattern was found, or the pattern otherwise.

So I wrote this script :

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `cat ids_list.csv`;
  do
    echo $i
    echo `grep $i log_FVAScope`
    if [[ ! res=$(grep $i log_FVAScope) ]]; then
      echo $i >> result.txt;
    else
      echo $res >> result.txt
    fi
  done
```

However, `result.txt` is empty, what am I doing wrong ?

Also it seems to be rather slow, how can I speed that up (`ids_list.csv` contains ~40k lines, the log file contains 700k lines) ?

EDIT : sample input :

**`ids_list.csv`** :

```
KBKEQO17564
SPXTCT769178
KBKFXS1952894
CDNEVL_4148105
BBR10000130794156
```

**log file** :

```
18:51:59.368 [pool-1-thread-4] INFO  c.s.m.x.liqor.filter.CodChainFilter - KBKEQO17564 excluded by CodeChain Filter
18:51:59.369 [pool-1-thread-5] INFO  c.s.m.x.liqor.filter.CodChainFilter - KBKFXS1952894 excluded by CodeChain Filter
18:51:59.369 [main] INFO  c.s.m.x.l.manager.FilterManagerImpl - waiting new deals to submit
18:51:59.369 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO  c.s.m.x.liqor.filter.CodChainFilter - CDNEVL_4148105 excluded by CodeChain Filter
18:51:59.369 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  c.s.m.x.liqor.filter.CodChainFilter - BBR10000130794156 excluded by CodeChain Filter
```

**Desired output (`result.txt`)** :

```
18:51:59.368 [pool-1-thread-4] INFO  c.s.m.x.liqor.filter.CodChainFilter - KBKEQO17564 excluded by CodeChain Filter
SPXTCT769178
18:51:59.369 [pool-1-thread-5] INFO  c.s.m.x.liqor.filter.CodChainFilter - KBKFXS1952894 excluded by CodeChain Filter
18:51:59.369 [main] INFO  c.s.m.x.l.manager.FilterManagerImpl - waiting new deals to submit
18:51:59.369 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO  c.s.m.x.liqor.filter.CodChainFilter - CDNEVL_4148105 excluded by CodeChain Filter
18:51:59.369 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  c.s.m.x.liqor.filter.CodChainFilter - BBR10000130794156 excluded by CodeChain Filter
```

Comment: Wrt speed, use awk instead.

Comment: Some sample input and expected output would be more helpful.

Comment: for reading a file line-by-line better use `while read line ; do ... ; done < file` - lines with spaces might kill you otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't need script actually. Below command does what you want.

```
while read line; do grep $line log_FVAScope >> result.txt ; done < ids_list.csv
```

I don't know the performance issue though.